# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Apache Tomcat/8.5.16

Tags: java, spring, macos, maven, tomcat

Am trying to set up a simple hello world app using JavaEE Spring Framework but running into the above issue once I deploy the .war file.

I have gone through a number of resources on the net but without success.

This is my app initializer class;

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{AppConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{AppConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/demoapp/*"};
}
}
```

And this the pom.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demoapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>demoapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I run `mvn clean instaal` then pick the .war file from the target directory which I then deploy to tomcat server using the "Manager App" option.

But once I visit the link `http://localhost:8080/demoapp/`, I get the page below;

[image]

My folder structure is as follows;

[image]

**Controller**

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 * Created by Lawrence on 17/07/2017.
*/
@Controller
public class HelloController {

  @RequestMapping("/hi")
  public String hi() {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

Some help or guidance on how to go about this, will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did your application deploy without errors?

Comment: No errors on deployment.

Comment: Does `http://localhost:8080/demoapp/hi` work?

Comment: @SteveC, no it does not. Getting HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Answer (score 0):

404 error is because server cant find the /demoapp/ ,can you post the controller where you have mapped the url /demoapp/.

Comment: chage these line    return new String[]{"/demoapp/*"}; to "/" and try http://localhost:8080/demo/hi

Comment: Getting the same error: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found